# Not able to install sonar runner in Mac (Sierra)

Tags: sonar-runner

I am trying to install sonar runner using below command.

brew install sonar-runner

Its giving me the error.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.

Please suggest.

Comment: I am also facing same issue...

Comment: Why not downloading the [official standalone distribution](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) ?

Comment: I am trying to install through HomeBrew.

Answer (score 29):

I think that sonnar-runner was replaced by sonar-scanner

```
brew install sonar-scanner
```